# How to iterate nested for loops referring to parent elements using Java 8 Streams and Lambdas?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the below piece of Code.

```
public static ModuleKey getDeployableModuleFromModulesList(List<Module> modules) {
        ModuleKey deployableModuleKey = null;
        for(Module module : modules) {
            List<Artifact> artifacts = module.getArtifacts();
            for(Artifact artifact : artifacts) {
                if(artifact.getType().equals("ear")) {
                    return module.getKey();
                } else if(!artifact.getType().equals("ear")) {
                    if(artifact.getType().equals("war")) {
                        deployableModuleKey = module.getKey();
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        return deployableModuleKey;
    }
```

This code finds the first 'deployableModuleKey' with key='ear' or last one with key = 'war'.
I want to achieve the same functionality as above using Java 8 Streams and Lambdas.

So far what I have tried is :

```
modules.stream().flatMap(e -> e.getArtifacts().stream())
  .filter(e -> e.getType().equals("ear")).findFirst()
  .orElseGet(() -> modules.stream().flatMap(e -> e.getArtifacts().stream())
  .filter(e -> e.getType().equals("war")).reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(null));
```

The above code snippet will return an object of type `Artifact` instead of `Module`. I want to obtain that module where the artifact matches the conditions. Once i find the module then I can return the key by doing `module.getKey()`.
To do this I would like to know how we refer elements of the parent for loop.

I am not sure if my Java 8 code is altogether correct.
Can someone help me in this regards ?

Comment: I would suggest you to break down this process across few functions. That doesn't mean Java 8 streams aren't encouraged to chaining operations, but to make them clear and atomic as much as possible.

Comment: I doubt using streams is better than your actual code. Streams are not good to hold state between intermediate operations. Plus, your current code makes one pass thru all the artifacts, while proposed solutions make two passes. If you want to do this with one pass only, I suggest you create your own collector (there are many questions about creating collectors here, just pick one and continue from there on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution to my problem.

```
public static ModuleKey getDeployableModuleFromModulesList(List<Module> modules) {
    Optional<ModuleKey> op = modules.stream().filter(module -> module.getArtifacts().stream().anyMatch(artifact -> artifact.getType().equals("ear"))).map(module -> module.getKey()).findFirst();
    if (!op.isPresent()) {
        op = modules.stream().filter(module -> module.getArtifacts().stream().anyMatch(artifact -> artifact.getType().equals("war"))).map(module -> module.getKey()).reduce((a, b) -> b);
    }
    return op.orElse(null);
}
```

Anyways, other solutions are also welcome. In case if someone adds another solution, I will try all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with streams is, once you've modified your stream using an intermediate operation such as `filter`or `map`, you can't refer back to the values from the previous operation. So you have to find workarounds in order to always keep (in your case the `Module`) the value you want to refer to in your stream. In the following solution, I open two secondary streams with `anyMatch` operations, which give a positive value if the module contains an artifact that contains the wanted key.

This should do the trick:

```
ModuleKey key = Optional.ofNullable(modules.stream().filter(m -> m.getArtifacts().stream()
    .anyMatch(a -> a.equals("ear"))).findFirst().orElse(modules.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.getArtifacts().stream().anyMatch(a -> a.equals("war")))
    .reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(null))).map(Module::getKey).orElse(null);
```

To find the first element, use `findFirst`, which returns an `Optional<T>`. We chain that `Optional` with `Optional#orElse`, which unwraps it and, if it's empty, returns another value (in this case using `reduce((a, b) -> b)` to find the last element). In case nothing has been found, we do not want the code to throw a `NullPointerException`. So before we call the `getKey` method, we wrap all this into an `Optional` with `Optional.ofNullable` and set the `orElse` to `null`, the default value specified in your code.

As a side note,

```
else if(!artifact.getType().equals("ear")) {
    if(artifact.getType().equals("war")) {
    }
}
```

can be reduced to

```
else if(artifact.getType.equals("war")) {
}
```

Comment: I get the following compile errors if I use your code snippet. `The method filter((<no type> m) -> {}) is undefined for the type List<Module>` and `The method getKey() is undefined for the type ModuleUtil`. The `getKey()` method is a part of the `Module` object.

Comment: @RITZXAVI I prototyped my code in notepad++ instead of my normal IDE, and there were a new glitches. I edited my answer to fix them, tell me if you're still experiencing issues.

Comment: Now i get this error. `The method orElse(Module) in the type Optional<Module> is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<Module>)`

Comment: @RITZXAVI Phew! Finally edited it in my IDE, this should do it. The error was that I was feeding `orElse`, which expects a `Module`, with the return value of `findFirst`, which is an `Optional`. I simply unwrapped that last `Optional` with another `orElse`. Again, tell me if you're still having issues.

Comment: Although, it is syntactically correct, but functionality wise, it is not doing what is am expecting. Anyways, I have figured out the solution which i will post. You can check it. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are aware that redundant `if` check in your old Java style code.

I have written your big single stream of operations by breaking down into smaller easy-peasy functions that anyone would understand.

```
public static ModuleKey getDeployableModuleFromModulesList(List<Module> modules) {

    return findEARKey(modules.stream())
            .orElse(findWARKey(modules.stream()).orElse(null));

}

public static Optional<ModuleKey> findEARKey(Stream<Module> moduleStream){

    return  moduleStream.flatMap(e -> e.getArtifacts().stream())
            .filter(e -> e.getType().equals("ear"))
            .map(Artifact::getKey).findFirst();
}

public static Optional<ModuleKey> findWARKey(Stream<Module> moduleStream){

    return  moduleStream.flatMap(e -> e.getArtifacts().stream())
            .filter(e -> e.getType().equals("war"))
            .map(Artifact::getKey).findFirst();
}
```

Comment: I think your code is good if I want the 'deployableModuleKey' with type='ear' **OR** 'war'.But instead, I want is the first 'deployableModuleKey' with type='ear'. If `ear` is not present then I want to return the last moduleKey with type= 'war'.

Comment: Besides, this code returns the artifact key instead of the module key

Comment: Yes, there is no attribute called `key` in the `Artifact` object.